# Inconsistent Data in variable

Tags: c++, pointers, structure

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
using namespace std;


    struct node
{
    node *next;
    node *prev;
    node *fnext;
    node *fprev;

    int device_number;
    int inode_number;
    int ref_count;
    bool locked;

};

node* Create(int inum,int dnum)
{
    node A;

    A.next=A.prev=A.fnext=A.fprev=NULL;

    A.inode_number=inum;
    A.device_number=dnum;
    A.ref_count=0;
    A.locked=false;

    return &A;
}

class Sample
{
public:
    Sample()
    {
        node*A= Create(0,0);

            cout<<A->device_number<<A->inode_number;
        Pass(A);
    }

    void Pass(node* A)
    {
        cout<<A->device_number<<A->inode_number;
    }


};
int main()
{
    Sample S;


    getch();
    return 0;

}
```

This is a small part of a big program. Here the focus is that i am getting garbage values like -868456546 in function Pass for node* A attribute values whereas in Constructor after using global function Create(int,int) for initializing node *A  I am getting correct values i.e 00. So this should not be happening as I am passing the same pointer to function Pass. What is the problem here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are returning the address of a local variable, which is undefined behavior:

```
node* Create(int inum,int dnum)
{
    node A;
    //...
    return &A;  // no good
}
```

When the function returns, that address no longer points to a valid instance of `node`, since `A` is a local variable.

You should dynamically allocate a new node, but then you have to manage your program to make sure you don't have memory leaks:

```
node* Create(int inum,int dnum)
{
    node* A = new node;
    //...
    return A;   
}
```

Also, all of your `.` will become `->`, since `A` is now a pointer.

Comment: can you explain about memory leaks please?

Comment: For each call to `new` you have to match it with a call to `delete`, otherwise you've leaked memory.